# youtubeplayerVIew stop when start new Video

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am able to intialize youtube video, but whenever i try to load another video it play existing one, i create a menthod, how to stop a youtube video which mwthod use to stop and load another video.

```
        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayerMain;

        private void init(final String VIdeoId) {
        rvMainl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        youTubeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (youTubePlayerMain != null)
        {
            try{
                youTubePlayerMain.pause();
                youTubePlayerMain.cueVideo(VIdeoId);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      else 
        {

          youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    youTubePlayerMain = youTubePlayer;
                    if (!b) {
                        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIdeoId); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(Youtube.this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(Youtube.this, youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

i find the issue , YouTubePlayer global and use second time to load video..

Comment: How are you trying to load another video?

Comment: i call this method and pass the url

Comment: but seconf time onInitializationSuccess not called

Comment: Try using [`release()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#release()) method to stop any loading or video playback and release any system resources used by this YouTubePlayer. However, after calling this method, any further interaction with this YouTubePlayer is forbidden. A new instance must be created to re-enable playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thise IS Worked for me.

**Youtube.java  (Activity)**

```
public class Youtube extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String API_KEY = Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY;
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    //http://youtu.be/<VIDEO_ID>
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "ZWub9VTECxQ";
    LinearLayout llVideo1, llvideo2, llVideo3,llVideo4;
    ImageView ivBack;

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    RelativeLayout rvMainl;
    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayerMain;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_youtube_player);
        rvMainl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rvMain);
        ivBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_iv_back);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llVideo1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frag_youtube_btn_one);
        llvideo2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frag_youtube_btn_two);
        llVideo3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frag_youtube_btn_three);
        llVideo4 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.frag_youtube_btn_four);
        llVideo4.setOnClickListener(this);
        llVideo1.setOnClickListener(this);
        llvideo2.setOnClickListener(this);
        llVideo3.setOnClickListener(this);
        ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                backButton();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

       if (youTubeView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
       {
           rvMainl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
           youTubeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
       else
       {
           backButton();
       }


    }


    private void backButton() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Youtube.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right_back, R.anim.right_to_left_back);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.frag_youtube_btn_one:
                youTubeView.destroyDrawingCache();
                youTubeView.destroyDrawingCache();

                init("DHFfXNES8gw");
                break;
            case R.id.frag_youtube_btn_two:
                init("RLcsVqx4IsU");
                break;
            case R.id.frag_youtube_btn_three:
                init("8Fx97V_Z3YY");
                break;
            case R.id.frag_youtube_btn_four:
                init("940qp3BdR6o");
                break;

        }
    }

    private void init(final String VIdeoId) {
        rvMainl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        youTubeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        if (youTubePlayerMain != null)
        {
            try{
                youTubePlayerMain.pause();
                youTubePlayerMain.cueVideo(VIdeoId);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }else {

            youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    youTubePlayerMain = youTubePlayer;
                    if (!b) {
                        try
                        {                        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIdeoId); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo

                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somrthing Went Wrong with this video ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(Youtube.this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(Youtube.this, youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

**fragment_youtube_player.xml**

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/youtube_iv_back"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
>             android:text="Everest Videos"
>             android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>             android:textSize="20dp" />
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:padding="10dp">
>
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:id="@+id/rvMain"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="horizontal"
>             android:weightSum="2">
>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>                 android:weightSum="2">
>
>
>                 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="120dp"
>                     android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>                     android:background="@drawable/border"
>                     android:orientation="vertical"
>                     android:padding="10dp">
>
>                      <LinearLayout
>                          android:padding="10dp"
>                          android:id="@+id/frag_youtube_btn_one"
>
>                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                          android:orientation="vertical"
>                          android:layout_height="match_parent">
>                          <ImageView
>                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                              android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube" />
>
>
>                          <TextView
>                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                              android:paddingTop="5dp"
>                              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>                              android:text="@string/str_video_one" />
>                      </LinearLayout>
>
>
>
>                 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>
>                 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="120dp"
>                     android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@drawable/border"
>                     android:orientation="vertical"
>                     android:padding="10dp">
>
>
>                     <LinearLayout
>                         android:id="@+id/frag_youtube_btn_two"
>
>                         android:padding="10dp"
>                         android:orientation="vertical"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                         android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube" />
>
>
>                     <TextView
>                         android:gravity="center"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>                         android:text="@string/str_video_two" />
>
>                     </LinearLayout>
>                 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>             </LinearLayout>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="horizontal"
>             android:weightSum="2">
>
>
>             <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="120dp"
>                 android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                 android:layout_weight="1"
>                 android:background="@drawable/border"
>                 android:orientation="vertical"
>                 android:padding="10dp">
>
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:id="@+id/frag_youtube_btn_three"
>
>                     android:padding="10dp"
>                     android:orientation="vertical"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                         android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube" />
>
>
>                     <TextView
>                         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>                         android:text="@string/str_video_three" />
>                 </LinearLayout>
>
>
>
>
>             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>
>             <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                 android:layout_weight="1"
>                 android:background="@drawable/border"
>                 android:orientation="vertical"
>                 android:padding="10dp">
>
>
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:id="@+id/frag_youtube_btn_four"
>                     android:padding="10dp"
>                     android:orientation="vertical"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="120dp">
>
>                     <ImageView
>                         android:id="@+id/imageView"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>                         android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube" />
>
>
>                     <TextView
>                         android:gravity="center"
>                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:paddingTop="5dp"
>                         android:text="EKOMILK SCAN." />
>                 </LinearLayout>
>
>
>
>
>             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
>     <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
>         android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIdeoId); use this line instead of  youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIdeoId);